# Using Android Emulator on OS X with .apk

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, apk, android-virtual-device

I'm new to using Android but am trying to take some screenshots using the Android SDK and the emulator.

I've managed to install the SDK on my mac, create an .avd (using one of the pre-configured device options) and can run it using the commands

`./emulator -avd AVD_for_7_WSVGA`

At this point i'm stuck though.

It seems like I can install my application I'd like to take screenshots of using avd, like this

```
./adb install /path/to/my.apk
2034 KB/s (17283416 bytes in 8.296s)
success
```

But cannot manage to get beyond the initial screen, the only other screen I can access is the other one I've included in this post.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to begin using the Android interface?

There is no bar at the bottom with home buttons etc, & I was hoping that there might be some default applications in the emulator such as a browser.

Thanks

[image: First Screenshot]
[image: Second Screenshot]

Comment: are you trying to take a screenshot of a wearable device? because that is the emulator you created

Comment: Ah - no i'm not, I just wanted to use the latest version of Android 4. Going to try with installing more SDK options and making a new avd not using Android 4.4W now... will see if that fixes things, thanks!

Comment: the W in 4.4 means wearable

Comment: got it, downloading 4.4.2 (API 19) now :)